# How to automatically add an unique data attribute to all elements in React?

Tags: reactjs, selenium-ide

I'm testing my React application using Selenium IDE and want to add an unique ID ("data-testid" for example) to all elements so I'd be able to select them easily.

So far I encountered libraries which accomplish that by adding some code ([react-html-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-id) for example), but I'm looking for a solution which will add these data attribute automatically on build time.

**For Example:**

Given a component

```
<SomeComponent /> // returns <span>Hello World<span>
```

When building the React application, it should be resulted with:

```
<span data-testid="123">Hello World</span>
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?